# GeoPosition of a point a specified GeoDistance away

Tags: geographics, geodesy

I am trying to plot text on a `GeoGraphic[]` at a certain distance from a defined point (located at `Interpreter["Airport"]["KEWR"]` for instance). I have tried to do this as such:

```
Text["New York",
    GeoPosition[Interpreter["Airport"]["KEWR"] +
    GeoDisplacement[Quantity[50, "NauticalMiles"], Quantity[0, "AngularDegrees"]]]]
```

Thinking this would write "New York" 50 nautical miles away from the airport of KEWR by first locating KEWR and then adding a displacement distance in the direction defined. Yet this fails with

> LatitudeLongitude: GeoPosition[Interpreter["Airport"]["KEWR"] + GeoDisplacement[50 nmi, 0°]] is not a valide location specification

As well I have tried to wrap my `Interpreter` in a `GeoPosition[]` function such as:

```
Text["New York",
    GeoPosition[GeoPosition[Interpreter["Airport"]["KEWR"]] +
    GeoDisplacement[Quantity[50, "NauticalMiles"], Quantity[0, "AngularDegrees"]]]]
```

But that just changes the error to

> LatitudeLongitude: GeoPosition[GeoPosition[{40.6925, -74.7687}] + GeoDisplacement[50 nmi, 0°]] is not a valide location specification

I'm sure there has to be a better way to accomplish this, but I can't seem to find the appropriate function within the documentation. Thanks for your help and time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`GeoDestination`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoDestination.html), which takes a location and vector as arguments.

```
kewr = Interpreter["Airport"]["KEWR"];
textloc = GeoDestination[kewr, GeoDisplacement[{Quantity[50, "NauticalMiles"], Quantity[0, "AngularDegrees"]}]];

GeoGraphics[{
  GeoMarker[kewr],
  Text[
    Style[Framed["New York", Background -> GrayLevel[.4, .3], FrameMargins -> 0, FrameStyle -> None, RoundingRadius -> 5], Bold, 20, ColorData[112, 1]], 
    textloc
  ]
 },
 GeoRangePadding -> Quantity[100, "Miles"]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was the function I was trying to find